# Bash if statement with input from another command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am fairly new to shell scripting so kindly bear with me. Here is what I want to do : Check the sar logs captured on a Linux server and if the load average for the past 1 minute is greater than the number of CPUs, print that load info. I used the following command  for this:

```
awk '/runq-sz/,/$^/' /var/log/sa/sar* | awk '{print $5}' \
| awk '{if ($1 > **CPU_COUNT**) print $0}' \
| grep -iv "ldavg" | head -n5
```

Ex, for a server with 16 CPUs:

```
awk '/runq-sz/,/$^/' /var/log/sa/sar* | awk '{print $5}' \
| awk '{if ($1 > **16**) print $0}' | grep -iv "ldavg" \
| head -n5
```

I get the following output which is correct and shows the command is working.

```
18.11
73.91
40.03
40.77
33.85
```

But what if instead of hardcoding CPU_COUNT, use a built-in Linux command like nproc? Is it possible to do so? If yes, how do I use it? I tried with something like this:

```
awk '/runq-sz/,/$^/' /var/log/sa/sar* | awk '{print $5}' \
| awk '{if ($1 > echo "$(nproc)") print $0}' \
| grep -iv "ldavg"
```

But it doesn't appear to be working. Am I missing something here? If this approach is incorrect how do I change the command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: do something like `amount=$(....command-to-get-n-count...)` and then pass that one to awk as shown in the marked duplicate.

Comment: `if N > echo....` is certainly not a valid numeric comparision in `awk`. Have a look at awk's `-v` option, which allows you to set awk variables when invoking awk.

Comment: You don't need all those separate commands and pipelines for this, just 1 awk command will do. Post a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you do this the right way.

Comment: BTW, it's pretty much never necessary to pipe from awk to `grep` or `head`; awk itself can do the work of both those tools. In the case of grep, use `/ldavg/ {next}` to skip lines that contain `ldavg`; in the case of `head`, use `NR > 5 { exit }`

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you're trying to use echo `$(nproc)` within `awk`, which won't work as expected. You need to pass the output of `nproc` to `awk` as a variable. You can do this using the -v option in awk. Here's how you can modify your command:

`awk -v cpu_count=$(nproc) '/runq-sz/,/$^/' /var/log/sa/sar* | awk -v cpu_count="$cpu_count" '{if ($1 > cpu_count) print $0}' | grep -iv "ldavg" | head -n5`

This should give you the desired output, with the number of CPUs dynamically determined by `nproc`.

Comment: No need to define `cpu_count` for the first `awk` command.  Unless, of course, you're going to do the sensible thing and merge that messy pipeline into one `awk` command, so that the first one is the only one.